# How to open a file from silverlight folder

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a xlsx file (New.xlsx) in a folder (Common) in my project (Silverlight side).

I want to access that file path on button click event and want to open that file.

I used below path :

```
string path = @"/Common/New.xlsx";
string path1 = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
excel.Visible = true;
```

But it is not working and I cannot open that file.

How to access file using file path in Silverlight?

Comment: From your description it is not known if the file is embedded as content or embedded as a resource.

Comment: I have set as content

Comment: From my readings I would suggest storing the file on the server side and have the client pull the file from the server.

Comment: I'm trying to get a better understanding of what you are trying to achieve. Do you need to just open Excel to a new blank wookbook or does the `New.xslx` act as a template for your user to fill in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options available to you for giving access to the file in question.

- You can get the content of the file as a stream and then ask the user to save the file via the `SaveFileDialog` class. The user would then have to select where they want to save the file and then open it manually.

```cs
public static byte[] GetBytesFromStream(Stream input){
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()){
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0){
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

public void OnButtonClick(){
    var templateUri = new Uri("/Common/New.xlsx, UriKind.Relative");
    var templateStream = Application.GetResourceStream(templateUri).Stream;
    var bytes = GetBytesFromStream(templateStream);
    var sfd = new SaveFileDialog() {
            DefaultExt = "xlsx",
            Filter = "Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files(*.*)|*.*",
            FilterIndex = 1                
    };

    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == true) {
        using (Stream stream = sfd.OpenFile()) {
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

- You can have the file stored server side and when the user clicks the button you tell the browser to get he file in question. The browser will then take over and ask the user if they want to save the file to disk or open using a known application.

```cs
public void OnButtonClick(){
    string link = "{the url/endpoint to the file on the server}";
    System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(link), "_blank");
}
```

- You can go down the `AutomationFactory` route but that would require alot of configuration changes like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12142924/5233410)

I think it's much better to have such things on the server rather than on the client side. The server is more well equipped to handle such processing.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
var TemplateUri = new Uri("/Common/New.xlsx, UriKind.Relative");
var stream = Application.GetResourceStream(sheetUri).Stream;
```

The file is deployed witin the xap file (which is a zip file) and cannot be handled by a normal file on the disk.

It is not clear for me what Excel library you are using, but it should allow you to load data from `Stream`.

Comment: I used " dynamic excel = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Excel.Application");  I want to Open a excel file. Can We do that?

Comment: Yes, you can, but your application must have elevated trust - check here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/cbf4b2cc-f889-4a63-91e4-0113f9af2819/problem-with-automationfactorycreateobjectexcelapplication?forum=silverlightarchieve

Comment: My advice is to try to have Excel processing on server side, as the layer allows to use standard .NET fwk (as opposed to Silverlight Runtime), thus allowing to easy handle the Excel file using high level libraries like ClosedXML. Server side processing also allows faster processing, as Web Servers are much more powerful than workstations.